# I was trying to get input with redux,all is fine but I can't figure out how to get input values

Tags: redux, react-redux

Trying to get user input with action,all is working i get my console.logs about how inputVal changes,but when I try to print this in

i get undefined in console

Should I use like mapDispatchToProps or I don't need this,since I'm passing actions as second param into mapStateToProps

actions:

```
export const inputChange = val => {
  return {
    type: INPUT_CHANGE,
    payload: val
  };
};
```

reducer:

```
import { INPUT_CHANGE } from './actionTypes';

const initialState = {
  inputVal: ''
};

export default (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case INPUT_CHANGE:
      return {
        ...state,
        inputVal: action.payload
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

mainPage:

```
const mapStateToProps = state => {
  console.log(state);

  return state;
};

class MainPage extends Component {

  onInput = e => {
    this.props.inputChange(e.target.value);
    console.log(this.props.inputChange(e.target.value));
  };

  render() {
    console.log(this.props.inputVal);
    return (
      <div>
         <input onChange={this.onInput}></input>
        <p>{this.props.}</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  {
    addToCart,
    removeFromCart,
    selectItem,
    inputChange
  }
)(MainPage);
```

combinedReducers:

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import AddItem from './addItem/reducer';
import InputReducer from './reducerInput';

export default combineReducers({
  AddItem,
  InputReducer
});
```

I've tried to `this.props.inputVal`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have combineReducers, you should use these keys to access in mapStateToProps.

From the redux docs:

> The state produced by combineReducers() namespaces the states of each
>   reducer under their keys as passed to combineReducers()
>
> You can control state key names by using different keys for the
>   reducers in the passed object. For example, you may call
>   combineReducers({ todos: myTodosReducer, counter: myCounterReducer })
>   for the state shape to be { todos, counter }.

So your mapStateToProps must be like:

```
const mapStateToProps = state => {
  console.log(state);

  return {
     inputVal: state.InputReducer.inputVal
  }
};
```

A minimal working code sandbox:

https://codesandbox.io/s/cold-meadow-pxtu3